# Using libcurl in g++

Tags: c++, compilation

Sorry, if stupid question, I'm kind of new in compiling a c++ program. I'm doing it with g++ and command line on Ubuntu. Last day I had to use external library `libcurl` -> `#include <curl/curl.h>`. So I installed it and added `-lcurl` flag when compiling. Like this `g++ vpn.cpp -o vpn -lcurl` It works nice, but when I want to execute the same file on another computer I get an error that curl is not installed. Is there a way to be able to include `#include <curl/curl.h>` in the output file, so I will be able to execute the file without installing additional libraries on host pc?

error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcurl-nss.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is what I tried

```sh
g++ -c vpn.cpp / ar rvs libcurl.a vpn.o / g++ vpn.cpp libcurl.a -DCURL_STATICLIB -lcurl -o vpns
```

Comment: This has little to do with the header file. The header file usually just tells the compiler that stuff exists. The stuff is actually in a library file that is being dynamically linked at runtime. You need to statically link cURL. Unfortunately cURL itself depends on a smurfload of other libraries. Someone has to have an good answer for "How do I statically link cURL?", so I'd start there.

Comment: One thing I do remember from suffering through this years ago is you have to define `CURL_STATICLIB`

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was googling and found some answers so I did: `g++ -c vpn.cpp`, `ar rvs libcurl.a vpn.o`. `g++ vpn.cpp libcurl.a -DCURL_STATICLIB -lcurl -o vpns` which worked without error in compilation, but the same error on host machine `error while loading shared libraries: libcurl-nss.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I think there's a `-static` or similar missing in the command line. I might have manually pointed the linker at a static-compiled library. Just checked. I did point directly at as static library. This was on Windows. It looks like I didn't bother trying to build static load on the Linux version. Probably because of the smurf-load of other libraries you need installed to go with it.

Comment: so when I would give up on trying to include it all, how should I progress? Should I make some `.sh` script to install it on host? Or something with `CMAKE` ?

Comment: In g++ on Linux, when linking to the 'Any' library, where both libAny.so and libAny.a reside in the same directory, the linker will prefer to link the .so.  Note that there is more than one way to order the linker to do what you want.  I sometimes find the least effort is to simply copy the libAny.a file to a convenient directory.  When you specify that directory to your linker (i.e. where that .a resides without .so), the linker will static link..